What is the minimum age to get into circuit racing?
I have been doing some research online and have found a few sources that claim kids as young as 14 can enter into circuit racing (not go cart racing). I am wondering since the minimum age to obtain a driver's license (in most countries) is usually higher than this, do such young drivers also get taught the basics of operating a vehicle to begin with or is this assumed knowledge they need to already have? What would be the general process for a young driver trying to get into motorsport this way?

When you drive on a circuit, there's no need for a "real life everyday driver license" but you need a pilot license (think F1 and Verstappen for instance). Some win races before being able to drive on open roads.
